# Solidity: fund a test contract

Tags: solidity, testing

I'm trying to write a test suite in Solidity for a few contracts contained in a single script. I can't alter the code in the contracts - they're not written by me, and I don't have the rights. I would like to be able to simulate a transaction between two contracts, but I can't figure out if there's a way for me to fund a contract from thin air (for testing) using Solidity. I'm assuming it would look something like:

```
contract testUser {
  constructor () {
    address(this).balance = 1 ether;
    }
```

Right now this is giving me an error in Remix (Expression has to be an lvalue), which I think is because this needs to be a storage thing, and this is trying to write it in memory, but adding `storage` to the line where I'm trying to fund the contract yields a syntax error. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can't just give your contract 1 ether money. The only way the contract receives ether is to implement [fallback function](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/contracts.html#fallback-function).

If you're using truffle it's quite easy to test your contracts. Please refer to the [documentation](https://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/testing).

Test code that sends ether could be as following:

**MyContract.sol:**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;


contract MyContract {
    address public owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function() external payable {
        owner.transfer(msg.value); // transfer funds to owner acc
    }

}
```

**migrations:**

```
let MyContract = artifacts.require("./MyContract.sol");
module.exports = function (deployer) {
     deployer.deploy(MyContract);
};
```

**test:**

```
let MyContract = artifacts.require("./MyContract.sol");

contract("MyContract", accounts => {

it("Test: receive payment", () => {
    let owner = accounts[0];
    let ownerInitialBalance;
    let sender = accounts[1];
    let amount = 100;

    return MyContract.deployed()
        .then(it => {
            ownerInitialBalance = Number(web3.eth.getBalance(owner));
            return it.sendTransaction({from: sender, value: amount});
        })
        .then(receipt => {
            console.log("Transaction Receipt = ", receipt);
            assert.equal(Number(web3.eth.getBalance(owner)), ownerInitialBalance + amount, "Owner balance check");
        })
  });
});
```

Comment: I'd been hoping to be able to handle it all inside a Solidity script, but I guess that's a no. This is a great answer, though - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can either send some ETH along with the deployment transaction, or do it later with [this](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) web3 command. In both cases, the function needs to be payable. ETH cannot be created from thin air, you have to transfer some from your accounts in `ganache` or `truffle develop` or Remix's JS-based VM which all give you lots of test ether and fast function execution.